# cc_quotes is not iterable at Reducer

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, redux, reducer

Tengo el error descrito en el título en uno de los reducer de mi proyecto. Lo que quiero es que a medida que una cotización llegue se introduzca en un array para lo cual uso `[...arrayActual, valorinsertar ]`.

Cabe destacar que en el ACTION viene un objeto {}. Lo ideal sería ir llenando un array de objetos pero en cuando uso el spread en el array obtengo ese error.

```
const initState = new Map({
  cc_quotes: [],
});

export default function myReducer(state = initState, action) {
  const cc_quotes = state.get("cc_quotes");
  switch (action.type) {
    case myAction.CC_ADD_QUOTE:
      return state.set("cc_quotes", [...cc_quotes, action.cc_quotes])
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: `cc_quotes` no es iterable, verifica su [tipo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) con un `console.log()` antes del `switch`. Si dices que `action` trae un objeto (también verifica que hay en `action.cc_quotes`), entonces el problema puede venir de `cc_quotes` que se supone que debe ser de [tipo Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Comment: Los array siempre con el operador typeof devuelven tipo object

Comment: utliza `isArray`, te deje su doc en la liga.